# mod rewrite won't accept my slash

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've just started with mod-rewrite and I can't figure something out.
This works

```
RewriteRule ^client-(.*)?$ clients.php?client=$1  [NC]
```

This doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)?$ clients.php?client=$1  [NC]
```

I'm trying to make it look like `client/nameclient` instead of `client-nameclient`
I don't understand why it won't take my slash character

I've searched and found nothing but things related to ending slash, I've even tried

```
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/client/$1  !-f
```

But makes no difference

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you have a typo, Because I see `clients.php` and `clienti.php`

```
RewriteRule ^client-(.*)?$ clients.php?client=$1  [NC]
                                 ^ this 

RewriteRule ^client/(.*)?$ clienti.php?client=$1  [NC]
                             and ^ are not same
```

Comment: No, that was just me copy paste, the issue is not that

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you need to escape your slash with a backslash.

```
RewriteRule ^client\/(.*)?$ clienti.php?client=$1  [NC]
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with AllowEncodedSlashes, when I added this line AllowEncodedSlashes On it said 500 internal error

Comment: No, it's different thing:((

Comment: is it something I'm missing? maybe not on this line but on another one?shoud I be adding something else? My code is this RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^client-(.*)-expo-(.*)-([0-9]*)$ clienti.php?client=$1&expo=$2&an=$3  [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^client/(.*)?$ clienti.php?client=$1  [NC,B](this diesn't work) I wrote the bigger one first cause it's more specific

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to write the solution here so that others with the same problem won't lose anymore precious time, well, the reason it didn't read the rule for client/client_name was that first of that a rule must be added for the client/ alone, le't say it redirects to index or whatever, thanks anyway

Comment: @adriana: It would be better if your posted it as an answer, be detailed and tell us what was wrong, then accept your own answer. That's the best way :)